# Could not load file or assembly 'ABC.dll, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#

We have an C# class library project which was created using .Net framework 3.5.In that C# project we add an assembly ABC.dll build using VS 2008 3.5 framework with version 5.5.0.0.
Now when we add ABC.dll with an updated version of 6.6.2.1 then in Designer view still get an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'ABC.dll, Version=5.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I am really stuck and cannot find the reason in-spite of adding 6.6.2.1 why the project is asking for 5.5.0.0 version dll?

We are now using C# Express Edition 2010 to open the project.

Comment: I think its an even older reference of 2.2.0.0 as seen in the error

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the reference is present and any dependent assemblies are referenced appropriately; you may need to make sure that the references have the property "SpecificVersion" set "false".

If the assemblies are present and the correct version - try cleaning the solution (Build | Clean Solution), as sometimes old versions linger in the project output folders and confuse Visual Studio.

Comment: It still didn't work.I am using C# Express Edition.I have even set Specific Vesrion to false.

Comment: Hmm. "Designer view", eh? Is this ASP.NET or Windows Forms or WPF?

Comment: It is an Windows Form.I have also tried cleaning Debug and Release folder.The .csproj also shows updated version i.e 6.6.2.1 after adding the updated dll into my project.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add an app.config file, telling your library which file to use when the .dll is called.

This should contain something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="ABC"
                                  publicKeyToken="8fe83dea738b45b7"
                                  culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="5.5.0.0"
                                 newVersion=" 6.6.2.1"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: It is still not working.Is this code useful when we call dll at run time?because I am having problem in Designer view where I am using some objects defined in dll.

Comment: This should work at runtime. You have to change the publicKeyToken to your dll's token. The app.config should reside on root in the library. Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/01/how-to-find-public-key-token-for-a-net-dll-or-assembly.aspx for how to find the publicKeyToken

Comment: But I don't want to sign the assembly with an public key as this dll also refers other dll and this will lead to assigning those dll also with public key.